# How to create a view with 4 tables - all tables are the same except for one field

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables that I would like to create a view.  All tables have the same columns except for one field.

Here is an example.  Then number of fields is about 15.

```
table A
a b c d f1

table B
a b c d f2

table C
a b c d f3

table D
a b c d f4
```

I would like to create a view that looks like this

```
a b c d f1 f2 f3 f4
```

I am using the lastest versionb my mysql on RDS.  What is the most efficient way to create this view using mysql syntax?

Added clarification.  the fields a,b,c,d will join to each other.  i.e.

```
A.a=B.a.=C.a=D.a and A.b=B.b etc....
```

Comment: Do you mean that the fields a b c d have the same structure or that they have the same content? How are the tables linked to each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "*most efficient way*"?  And when you say "*create this view*", do you mean that you want a query that returns the result viewed in that fashion, or that you actually want to create a [stored view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html)?

Comment: Basically all fields are one big composite key

Answer (score 0):

Given the assumption, your fields `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are resembling an unique key to your purpose (please clarify if otherwise), your [`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-syntax.html)-Syntax would look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW your_view AS 
SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c, A.d,
       A.f1, B.f2, C.f3, D.f4
FROM   A
INNER JOIN B ON A.a = B.a AND A.b = B.b AND A.c = B.c AND A.d = B.d
INNER JOIN C ON A.a = C.a AND A.b = C.b AND A.c = C.c AND A.d = C.d
INNER JOIN D ON A.a = D.a AND A.b = D.b AND A.c = D.c AND A.d = D.d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT * FROM tableA NATURAL JOIN tableB NATURAL JOIN tableC NATURAL JOIN tableD
```